# Is SQL Server Analysis Services the right choice for my scenario?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, business-intelligence

I have to use SQL Server Analysis Services to apply clustering and regression alog's on my data and make an analysis. I have sql server 2008 R2 installed but SQL Server Analysis Services are not installed.
Do i have to install 'Business Intelligence Development Studio' or what should i install to use analysis services.

In short I have to make a trained clustering model based on my data and then use that model from c# desktop application.Is SQL Server Analysis Services the right choice for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Analisys Services is a server component and should be installed on your SQL Server instance. Then you can use BI Development Studio to create SSAS projects.

Update.

SSAS is included in Standart and Enterprse editions of SQL Server 2008. Here is [feature list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for SQL Server 2008, specificaly look for Multi-Dimentional Analysis and Data Mining.

Here is article on [New Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of SSAS.

Comment: whether BI Development Studio provide me facility to create a trained clustering model based on my data and then use that model from c# desktop application?

Comment: Model, broadly, is a set of rules and relationships. However, you'll need actual data and you'll need an "engine" to make those rules produce a meaningful output. So you need to install SSAS at least on local instace on SQL Server Engine. Refer to SSAS installation manual, where it is described in good detail.

Comment: Right now I have SQL server 2008 R2 express edition installed, should I uninstall it and install SQL server 2008 R2 developer edition to use analysis services?? Also will I be able to perform data mining things on my data with SSAS-like what 'RapidMiner' is doing?  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You need Standard or Entrprise edition. I'm not familiar with "RapidMiner", so cannot comment.

Comment: You are welcome. If your question is answered, you can mark it by clicking "tick" icon next to it. You may also upvove a good answer.